# How do JavaScript Bitwise operators work?

Tags: javascript, operators

I know `bitwise` operators are Bitwise Not, means 1 becomes 0 and 0 becomes 1

But my question is related to below:

```
var c = 5.87656778;
alert(~c);
```

**alerts -6**

```
var c = 5.87656778;
alert(~~c);
```

**alert  5**

Can someone throw somelight on this?

Comment: jQuery developers "supposedly" are familiar with javascript...

Comment: @GonçaloVieira: eh, I dunno, I wouldn't count on that ;-)

Comment: just read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers

Comment: @maerics hence why I "" the word supposedly :D

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it converts the number to an integer by truncating the fractional part, and performs the usual bitwise operations on that integer representation.

MDN has some pretty good [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) on this.

```
 5 in binary is = 00000000000000000000000000000101 =  5
                  --------------------------------
~5 in binary is = 11111111111111111111111111111010 = -6
```

Answer (score 0):

They all work on 32-bit signed integers. Except for the zero-fill right shift, `>>>` which works on 32-bit unsigned integers.

So any float is converted to an integer via truncation.